# Issue with NSSlider and IBDesignable

Tags: swift, interface-builder, ibdesignable

So I've hit a strange issue that looks to be a bug. Whenever adding 'User Defined Runtime Attributes', it loses the style of the slider. If the @IBInspectable is it's default value, it's fine. But once an attribute is stored, it overrides the style. Because this is difficult to explain, I attached an image.

On the left is without the IBInspectable, and the right is with an IBInspectable variable set. I want it to look like the left one with the dark style.

[image: Slider issue]

and some code:

```
@IBDesignable
public class customSlider: NSSlider {
    @IBInspectable public var nonZero: Bool = false {
        didSet{ 
        //does a task
        }
    }
}
```

I think this issue is with more then just an NSSlider, but to all NSControl objects. Let me know if theres a fix. Thanks.

Comment: sliderOutlet.tintColor = UIColor(white: 0.3, alpha: 1)  // greyscale

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cymnnltk3fmt7s0/sliderOptions.png

Comment: It is correct in interface builder. but not when i build the app. Why does it change? And I don't have the color options in Interface Builder. The tint color variable is not working. Slider does not have a member named 'tintColor'.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a bug.

Comment: I am not seeing this problem on Xcode 7.0 (7A220).